# Is it possible to produce a type error if an argument already exists in a map?

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a protected map that contains some values, and a class method that adds new values to the map.

```js
class Container {
  protected readonly values: Map<PropertyKey, number> = new Map();
  
  public addValue(key: PropertyKey, value: number): void {
    if (this.values.has(key)) {
      throw new Error('key already exists');
    } else {
      this.values.set(key, value);
    } 
  }
}
```

Is it possible to type this class and function so that successive calls to the `addValue` function would produce a type error if the key already exists in the map?  Having it throw an Error is easy enough, but I'm wondering if it is possible to perform this check with the Typescript compiler.

```js
const container = new Container();
container.addValue('foo', 1); // valid
container.addValue('bar', 2); // valid
container.addValue('foo', 3); // invalid - foo already exists!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Container<K extends PropertyKey = never> {
  protected readonly values: Map<K, number> = new Map();

  public addValue<P extends PropertyKey>(key: Exclude<P, K>, value: number) {
    if (this.values.has(key as any as K)) {
      throw new Error('key already exists');
    } else {
      this.values.set(key as any as K, value);
    }
    return this as Container<K | P>
  }
}

let container = new Container()
  .addValue('foo', 1) // valid
  .addValue('bar', 2) // valid
  .addValue('foo', 3) // invalid - foo already exists!
```

Comment: Nice, although it all goes wrong if consumer creates a container object on its own, then tries to `container.addValue` over consecutive statements. Only by embracing proper immutability does this become foolproof.

Answer (score -1):

Certainly, it's doable to utilize TypeScript for making sure that consecutive calls to the `addValue` function are type-checked and trigger an error if the key is already present in the map. You can accomplish this by creating a conditional type that verifies if a `key` exists in the `map`, and then apply it as the return type of the `addValue` function. Meaning that If it already exists, then the type becomes `never`. this will result in a type error when you try to use the return value, hence preventing you from adding duplicate keys.